Some formula on anti-symmetrization: general formula for anti-symmetrization $A^{i_1 \cdots i_n} X_{[a} \bar{A}_{i_1 \cdots i_n]}$
Let $A, \bar{A}$ be the totally-anti-symmetric tensor.  Here my convention for $A_{[a_1,   \cdots, a_n]}= \frac{1}{n!} (A_{a_1 \cdots a_n} +  \cdots)$
I want to find some general formula for
\begin{align}
A^{i_1 \cdots i_n} X_{[a} \bar{A}_{i_1 \cdots i_n]} = \cdots
\end{align}
For $n=2$ by explicit computation I found
\begin{align}
A^{bc} X_{[a} \bar{A}_{bc]} = \frac{1}{3!} A^{bc} [ 2 X_{a} \bar{A}_{bc} - 4 X_{b} \bar{A}_{ac}]  
\end{align}
From this naively I can guess, the expressions will be written as a combination of $X_{a} \bar{A}_{a_1 \cdots a_n}$ and $X_{a_1} \bar{A}_{a a_2 \cdots a_n}$ due to totally-antisymmetric properties of $A, \bar{A}$.
It is quite hard to compute for $n=3$, after some explicit computation I founds
\begin{align}
A^{bcd} X_{[a} \bar{A}_{bcd]} = \frac{1}{4!} A^{bcd} [ 6 X_{a} \bar{A}_{bcd} - 18 X_{b} \bar{A}_{acd} ] 
\end{align}
I want to know whether my formula for $n=3$ corrects and know how to generalized this for arbitrary $n$? If possible I want to extend the rank of $X$ demanding $X$ be symmetric or anti-symmetric for simplicity.

In general,
$$
A^{i_1 \cdots i_n} X_{[a} {\bar A}_{i_1 \cdots i_n]} = \frac{1}{n+1} X_a A^{i_1 \cdots i_n} {\bar A}_{i_1 \cdots i_n} - \frac{n}{n+1} X_{i_1} A^{i_1 \cdots i_n} {\bar A}_{a i_2 \cdots i_n } 
$$

can you explain or describe how to obtain that formula?

@phy_math - There are $n+1$ different places where the index $a$ can be placed. Due to the complete antisymmetry of ${\bar A}$, $n$ of those index placements are identical. That gives us the formula.
